# MVVMCross MvxDialogFragment Restore Issue - Does not have MvxFragmentPresentationAttribute

Tags: xamarin, dialog, mvvmcross

I have upgraded to the latest version of MvvmCross (6.4.1) from 4.2.3. I and using Xamarin Android not Xamarin forms

In the view which initiates the dialog I do the following

- Create dialog fragment derived from MvxDialogFragment
- Assign a view model to it
- Then call ShowView on the fragment

However when I rotate the device it fails in OnCreate with the message

```
Your fragment is not generic and it does not have MvxFragmentPresentationAttribute attribute set!
```

This did not happen in 4.2.3. The reason I create dialog this way is that I want it to use different view models depending on where I need this dialog. For example I want to show a different list of data, but in the same format in the dialog.

It seems this will only work if we apply the MvxFragmentPresentationAttribute which needs the type of view model to be defined at design time rather than run time.

Is there anything I can do to achieve this

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: If you just add this property to your Activity, `ScreenOrientation = ScreenOrientation.Portrait,` it seems to solve the issue

Answer (score 0):

If you somehow need to specify the ViewModel type at runtime, you can instead of decorating the class with the `MvxFragmentPresentationAttribute` let it implement, `IMvxOverridePresentationAttribute` and return it there with the appropriate ViewModel to be presented in.

Something like:

```cs
public class MyDialog : MvxDialogFragment, IMvxOverridePresentationAttribute
{
    public MvxBasePresentationAttribute PresentationAttribute(MvxViewModelRequest request)
    {
        return new MvxFragmentPresentationAttribute
        {
            ActivityHostViewModelType = myDynamicType
        };
    }
}
```

Where you implement some kind of logic to get the `myDynamicType` somewhere.

However, you should be able to use `MvxDialogFragmentPresentationAttribute` instead though and the presenter will attempt to use the topmost Android Activity to present it in if you provide a `null` ref as the `ActivityHostViewModelType`.

Comment: Hi @Cheesebaron, Thanks for responding. In my case, its not the ActivityHostViewModelType, its the ViewModelType for the dialog. When I added the attribute, I set the ViewModelType, it then failed because it cannot create a non-singleton view model type of the type I specified. Is/there any references/articles about creating dialogs manually rather than using the navigation service. By that I mean var mycustomFragment = new MyCustomDialogFragment(); myCustomDialogFragment.ViewModel = new MyCustomDialogFragmentViewModel(); myCustomDialogFragment.Show(fragmentManager, fragmentTag)

Comment: Please post the full error message when using MvxDialogFragmentPresentationAttribute

Comment: The issue was that when I set the ViewModelType in the MvxDialogFragmentPresentation attribute, that view model could not be constructed due to the fact it needed a parameter passed to the constructor. I think I need to rethink my view model to avoid having to pass in the parameter. I should probably set this up in the fragment by passing that data as an argument to the fragment.

Comment: I have a few situations in my app where I do not use the navigation service to create views and view dialogs. How should I create these to make them behave as if they have been created through the navigation service. For example I have dialogs that I create from a view